# Redirecting an IP Address to subdomain on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using Windows Server 2012 at AWS.

I've configured my websites on AWS like; asd.com sdf.com asd.asd.com etc. That's ok.

I have another website which must be run at Nginx. So, I figured it out on 8008 Port.

Now, I serve my nginx website at IP address like; http:111.111.111.111:8008. But, I want to serve like; subsite.asd.com

Which service should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

A **DNS name** resolves only to an **IP address**. It cannot contain a port.

You will need a service running on port 80 to redirect request, or pass-through requests, to port 8008.